# Completion and Algebraic Closure

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Suppose we start with a valued field $K$ and we want to find a field extension of $K$ that is algebraically closed and complete. The usual process is: Consider the completion $\hat{K}$ of $K$, then its algebraic closure $\bar{\hat{K}}$ and then again the completion $\hat{\bar{\hat{K}}}$. Since completions of algebraically closed fields are algebraically closed, this gives what we want (e.g. this is what is done for $p$-adic numbers: $\mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}_p \rightarrow \hat{\mathbb{Q}}_p \rightarrow \mathbb{C}_p$).

Why don't we just build the algebraic closure of $K$ and then its completion? This would also give us a complete, algebraically closed field, but with one step less.

Comment: The $p$-adic numbers are also a completion of the rationals, but using a different [absolute value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value_%28algebra%29) than the usual, Archimedean one.

Comment: @McFry Oh, cool. I did not know that (thought the fact that the $p$-adic metric on the integers extends to the rationals should've been obvious). It's hard some times to realize that $\Bbb Q$ not always is a subset of $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To amplify @McFry, the rationals have a very manageable set of absolute values (one for each prime, plus $\infty$), while an algebraic closure of $\Bbb Q$ has *many, many* absolute values. You’d be hard put to it to choose one to complete $\Bbb Q$ with respect to, but the outcome would always be a $\Bbb C_p$, for some $p$. This is even the case for $p$“=”$\infty$: Let $\omega$ be a cube root of unity, $\omega^2+\omega+1=0$, and look at $K=\Bbb Q(\omega,i)$. There are two archimedean absolute values on $K$, one where $\mid\omega-i\mid<1$, and one where $\mid\omega-i\mid>1$, but completion of both gives you $\Bbb C$.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Is it true for any field $K$ that both procceses described in the question give the same results (as in the case $\mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}_p$)?

Comment: I don’t know, @Martin. There may be some aspects of this question that involve fancy set theory or logic, both of which I’m not well acquainted with.